# How to check if the output is zip or tar.gz and unzip/untar accordingly?

Tags: python

I am trying to unzip or untar file after reading from output with if else statement but its not working for me.

Here is my code:

```
import tarfile
import zipfile

download_url = https:github.com/sergi/go-diff/archive/refs/tags/v1.2.0.zip

target_path = primresult['download_url'].split("/")[-1]
#will give me output as v1.2.0.tar.gz or v1.2.0.zip depending on the download_url
print(target_path) 

#Prim query
primQueryURL = requests.get('http://example.com?query={"username":"xxxxx","token":"xxxxxx","facility":"COMPONENT_QUERY", "prim":"'+ primNumber +'"}', timeout = 10,  headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"})
primresult = json.loads(primQueryURL.text)
print(primresult['source_code_url'])

#download the software
url = primresult['source_code_url']
download_url = primresult['download_url']
print(primresult['download_url'].split("/")[-1])
resp = requests.get(url, stream=True, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('xxxx', 'xxxxx'))

if resp.status_code == 200:
    with open(target_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(resp.raw.read())

target_path = primresult['download_url'].split("/")[-1]

def process_archive(download_url):
    if download_url.endswith('.zip'):
        # process zip
        target_path = download_url.split("/")[-1]
        zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(target_path)
        zip_ref.extractall()
        zip_ref.close()
    elif download_url.endswith('.tar.gz'):
        # process tar.gz
        target_path = download_url.split("/")[-1]
        tar = tarfile.open(target_path)
        tar.extractall()
        tar.close()
process_archive('download_url')
```

Could anyone please help to read from `target_path` if it's `zip`, unzip it, else check if it's `tar.gz` and untar it.

Comment: Agree @martineau now that the question is formatted, I am unsure of the issue other than checking if file is zip or tar. The 'primresult' isn't defined and the download_url value needs quotes as well as slashes after https.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion . my target_path will give me output as target_path=v1.2.0.zip or if the download url ends with tar.gz , it will give me target_path=v1.2.0.tar.gz (just a ex.) . Now i want to read the output if its zip , unzip else untar it?

Comment: I added the code to open the tar file. However, you will need to download the file before you can open it. You can use the requests library to download the file then pass the filename. This also assumes you are running your script from the same directory that you download the tar file to.

Comment: Somehow I am not able to paste my code here , but i am downloading 1st by using :-#download the software
url = primresult['source_code_url']
download_url = primresult['download_url']
print(primresult['download_url'].split("/")[-1])
resp = requests.get(url, stream=True, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('xxxx', 'xxxxx')), but when i added the if/elif , its not able to unzip the file .   Yes this is same path

Comment: I also tried like this but its not doing unzip :-                                                                       
def process_archive(download_url):
    if download_url.endswith('.zip'):
        # process zip
        zip = zipfile.is_zipfile(target_path)
        zip.extractall('.')
    elif download_url.endswith('.tar.gz'):
        # process tar.gz
        target_path = download_url.split("/")[-1]
        tar = tarfile.open(target_path)
        tar.extractall()
        tar.close()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below approach.
The file must be downloaded to a staging location.Then check the file extension and extract the file to a location on the server.

```
import tarfile
import zipfile
import urllib.request
download_url = "https://github.com/sergi/go-diff/archive/refs/tags/v1.2.0.zip"
target_path = download_url.split("/")[-1]
print(target_path)
staging="D:\\Learning\\staging\\"
try:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(download_url, staging+target_path)
    if '.zip' in target_path:
        # process zip
        zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(staging+target_path)
        zip_ref.extractall(staging)
        zip_ref.close()
    elif 'tar.gz' in target_path:
        print('yo1')
        # process tar.gz
        tar = tarfile.open(staging+target_path)
        tar.extractall(staging)
        tar.close()
except Exception as e: print(e)
```